# Why does `package` get highlighted like a keyword in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I noticed that `package` is recognized as a keyword in a TypeScript file opened in VS2012 with the lastest TypeScript as wekk as in the [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=package%0A). Why is that?

Comment: `package` is a reserved word in es.

Answer (score 2):

It is a contextually reserved keyword in JavaScript. This is to support a possible future packaging system. This reservation came with ES5 strict mode https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html

> Use of the identifiers "implements", "interface", "package", "private", "protected", "public", and "static" is prohibited within strict mode code. (11.6.2.2).